# Do I start with a flow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, outlook, onedrive

We have a process which I think going forward needs to be a "flow" or maybe a "workflow".

**Overview**

A Sales team member submit a request for a design to the design team. Once accepted by design manager, it is allocated to a team member using tasks

Below is a slightly more detailed description of how it currently works, so hopefully the best way forward could be suggested.

Apologies if i'm unclear on terminology, i'm just a nerd not an IT professional....

- An Outlook 2010 custom form based on a task (remember those?) with
  about 10-15 fields is launched and filled in.
- When submitted the form
  is emailed to the manager of the design team.
- Manager reviews form info, and if sufficient (no missing / vague info):
- Accepts it, runs some VB script which

  - copies form data to a new row in a large Excel
    file for records
  - Allocates the task to a team member
  - Creates job folder on network
  - Saves attachments from submission as files in job folder
  - Creates HTML viewable version of the form review during design

So, now we're apparently in the age of Sharepoint / Infopath / Powerapps / Flow / Onedrive it would seem there are better and easier ways...  but at this point it just looks like 1000 ways to start...

We'd like to have

- a "task list" visible on sharepoint by all parties, but only editable by design team
- continue with receivng outlook tasks representing each job
- we've started using job folders in onedrive, so things will live there in future

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :) I really just can't figure out where to start or even if i'm heading down the right path for this process...